# Bootstrap: Use div as modal only for xs screens?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a two column Bootstrap layout on small screens and up. For the **extra small** size class, I'd like to hide the second column from the normal flow, and *instead use it as the contents for a modal*.

Is that possible in an elegant way (i.e. without moving it around the DOM with Javascript)?

Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Main Column -->
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
        Main contents blah blah blah
    </div>
    <!-- Secondary Column -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        Other contents. These appear normally in sm, md, lg. In xs, it should be the contents of a modal.
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample modal (in which the secondary column should be displayed):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is where I want the contents from the secondary column
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by using jQuery's `$.html()` function to get the html of the column and then using `$.html()` again to place it in the modal. This, combined with Abdulla's recommendation, should give you what you want. Here is a demo I created:

```js
$("#myModalBtn").click(function() {
 $("#myModal .modal-body").html($("#myModalContent").html());
 $("#myModal").modal("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <!-- Main Column -->
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
     Main contents blah blah blah
     
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary visible-xs" id="myModalBtn">Launch demo modal</button>

    </div>
    <!-- Secondary Column -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 hidden-xs" id="myModalContent">
     Other contents. These appear normally in sm, md, lg. In xs, it should be the contents of a modal.
    </div>
 </div>  
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    This is where I want the contents from the secondary column
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Click on <kbd>Run Code Snippet</kbd> then click on the "Full Page" link to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hidden-` property in Bootstrap.

1. Hidden-xs - Hidden in Extra Small
2. Hidden-sm - Hidden in Small
3. Hidden-md - Hidden in Extra Small
4. etc ..

Check this [Responsive utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

Comment: That solves the first part, but how do I then use it as the contents of a modal?

Comment: can you elobarate more

Comment: Added some example code to the question. Basically: how can I make a column function normally at >= small, but be the contents of a modal at extra small?